# runit call script with start/stop

Tags: bash, sh, runit

I've some SysVinit scripts with `start/stop`, they are used for remote server deployment, as now i am using runit in other deployment purpose, and don't want to duplicate the scripts (maintenance reason). Is it possible that `runit` invokes these scripts? or other approach? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you can use these scripts unmodified with `runit`. Runit expects the service started with `run` to remain in the foreground and *not exit*.

A SysVInit script expects the *opposite* behavior.  Because it does not perform any process monitoring (and the lack of process monitoring is presumably why you are switching to `runit`), SysVInit scripts expect services to run in the background, and will exit after starting the service.

These are two fundamentally incompatible models.

You could consider using `systemd` instead of `runit`, which provides good process monitoring while *also* being able to follow processes that fork.

Comment: thx a lot for the clarification, as I use `ansible` to control the deployment, the best approach i can work out, is using `jinja2` template to switch between two deployment, so every detail will be managed inside same template file. Kind of workaround.